# How to connect elastic cluster from application running in docker

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am trying to migrate my python application into docker image. current code is crawling data from web and inserting in elastic search cluster running on different machines.

how do define url of external ip of es cluster in docker-compose

Comment: how is your python code taking the es cluster ip without using docker?

Comment: declare all resources in one config.py file and other python file is reading from here.

Comment: you can do the same with docker you can mount your config file to the desired location and have your python program read from the config file
ref: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: @jaswanth thanks a lot for your reply. its working for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass external es ip as environment variable in docker-compose:

```
  your-python-service:
    image: ...
    ...
    environment:
      ES_ADDR: your_es_ip_here
```

And then read env in your python code:

```
es_arr = os.environ["ES_ADDR"]
```

This is one of many possible problem solutions.